# Install Ubuntu on Thunderbolt/USB4

Tags: system-installation, mac, thunderbolt

I am wondering if it is possible to install Ubuntu on a 2020 Mac Air (before M chips) when it only has two thunderbolt/usb4 ports and a headphone jack.

When I ordered the machine, I was thinking it would have more ports.

Is it possible to get an adapter and make one of those thunderbolt ports bootable?

Comment: If you have an Intel-based MacBook, both of those ports support booting via external media. You may need to initiate it with BootCamp before the system boot sequence will respond to connected devices, though, as Apple is very controlling about how its products are used.